# FATAL EXCEPTION: UpdateThread, null pointer Exception

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite, andengine

I have made three activities for a game:

1.`gameActivity`  -- calls method from databaseActivity for updating score
2.`databaseActivity`  --- calls update method from `dataHelperActivity`
3.`dataHelperActivity` --- has update method

> unable to call datahelper in `databaseActivity`, getting `NullPointerException`.

```
01-25 12:22:38.352: E/AndroidRuntime(2869): FATAL EXCEPTION: UpdateThread
01-25 12:22:38.352: E/AndroidRuntime(2869): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-25 12:22:38.352: E/AndroidRuntime(2869):     at com.snakegame.database.SnakeDatabase.manipulateCurrency(SnakeDatabase.java:1597)
01-25 12:22:38.352: E/AndroidRuntime(2869):     at com.snakegame.classic_mode.SnakeGameWithLevelActivity$16.run(SnakeGameWithLevelActivity.java:1779)
01-25 12:22:38.352: E/AndroidRuntime(2869):     at org.andengine.engine.handler.runnable.RunnableHandler.onUpdate(RunnableHandler.java:42)
 01-25 12:22:38.352: E/AndroidRuntime(2869):    at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onUpdateUpdateHandlers(Engine.java:596)
 01-25 12:22:38.352: E/AndroidRuntime(2869):    at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onUpdate(Engine.java:585)
 01-25 12:22:38.352: E/AndroidRuntime(2869):    at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onTickUpdate(Engine.java:548)
01-25 12:22:38.352: E/AndroidRuntime(2869):     at org.andengine.engine.Engine$UpdateThread.run(Engine.java:820)
01-25 12:22:38.398: D/AndEngine(2869): SnakeGameWithLevelActivity.onPause @(Thread: 'main')
01-25 12:27:38.398: I/Process(2869): Sending signal. PID: 2869 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Get rid of your null pointer. That'll fix it! - We can't help since you didn't post any code or any details of the exception.

Comment: what wud be a suitable approach?

Answer (score 2):

Add this in your manifest file

```
<activity
        android:name="databaseActivity"
        android:label="@string/title" >
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the problem. While you are calling `DatabaseHelper` class, pass the instance of the current `Activity` to that as below:

```
 DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this); //Here this is the instance of the current activity
```